# Making this spatial query more efficient

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial

I have 2 tables:

`tZipCodeNoCity` with `ZipCode` and `PointGeography` 
and `MBLPosition` with `Latitude` and `Longitude`

In this query I'm finding closest ZipCode to my positions. It's "poor mans" geocoding :)

How do I write this query so I don't have to do this `SELECT TOP 1` inline?
It's pretty slow with even 150 devices (like 20 seconds)

I had to include 150 mile radius into this subselect to get it faster

```
SELECT LastPositions.DeviceId, P.Description, P.Latitude, P.Longitude, P.Speed, P.DeviceTime,
(
SELECT TOP 1 ZC.ZipCode
FROM dbo.tZipCodeNoCity ZC
WHERE ZC.PointGeography.STDistance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(P.Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(P.Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)) < 150 * 1609.344
ORDER BY ZC.PointGeography.STDistance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(P.Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(P.Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326))
) 
            FROM dbo.MBLPosition P
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT D.DeviceId, MAX(P.PositionKey) LastPositionKey 
                FROM dbo.MBLPosition P
                INNER JOIN IDATTApplication.dbo.MBLDevice D ON P.DeviceKey = D.DeviceKey
                GROUP BY D.DeviceId
            ) LastPositions ON P.PositionKey = LastPositions.LastPositionKey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a project I worked on about 12 years ago, I ran a query along these lines to reduce the list of possibilities before doing the actual distance calculation:

```
WHERE zip.lat < my.lat + 0.5 && zip.lat > my.lat - 0.5 
    && zip.long < my.long + 0.5 && zip.long > my.long - 0.5
```

From that subset, I calculate the actual distance between the two points and sort on it.  You'll have to adjust the "0.5" portion as appropriate to get a big enough box to be sure you're going to get a hit.

And I would imagine that there's a better way than `STPointFromText` to create your point object.  Could you use `STPointFromWKB`?  Could you convert to the `geography` type once?

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) for an example of creating your point via `SET`.

```
DECLARE @p geography;
SET @p = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(P.Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(P.Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326);

SELECT TOP 1 ZC.ZipCode
FROM dbo.tZipCodeNoCity ZC
WHERE ZC.PointGeography.STDistance(@p)) < 150 * 1609.344
ORDER BY ZC.PointGeography.STDistance(@p))
```

Comment: It's kind of temporary solution, I didn't want to add geography column on MBLPosition because all CRUD done via Entity Framework ORM and there is no spatial support there. I was thinking maybe some kind of MIN() query possible and then join